# Large list of quotes

Tags: data-request, language, api

I am looking for a large database / list of quotes I can use. Preferably famous quotes / quotes by famous people. I have tried looking for a brainyquote API or something, but couldn't find one. If there isn't a large downloadable list of data, what is a website that would allow me to crawl their quotes / has an API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you seen [WikiQuote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Main_Page) by the [Wikimedia Foundation](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Home)?

There is an API endpoint at `http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php` which uses the standard [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) for there are [API clients in many different languages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code).

---

**EDIT:** Two WikiQuote API-specific links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762688/wiki-quotes-api and http://bwgz57.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/in-search-of-quotes/